# VisualStudio 2017 npm при востановлении пакетов ставит более старую версию

Tags: visual-studio, bootstrap, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-2017

В своём проекте я решил использовать 4 версию `bootstrap` (`4.0.0-beta.2`). Прописал это в файл `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
...
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
...
```

Если в VisualStudio я кликаю на папке NPM, выбираю bootstrap и жму `обновить пакет` то устанавливается версия `4.0.0-beta.2`, всё как надо. Но если я кликну на самой папке `NPM` востановить пакеты, то он ставит снова старую версию `3.3.7` (то есть не то, что указано в `project.json`).
Почему такое поведение и как его отключить, исправить?

Я использую `ASP.NET Core 2.0 React Template`, если это имеет значение.

Неприятное то что пакеты в VS 2017 востанавливаются автоматически, и это скидывает версию 4 на 3... очень неприятно. Автоматическое восстановление можно отключить в настройках, это частично решает проблему, но всё-таки неприятно и непонятно почему востановление пакетов ставит другую версию отличную от настроек в файле `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно npm пакеты прописываются в файле `package.json` а не `project.json`

Comment: Такой и был в проекте, просто написал неправильно, исправил.

Comment: А package-lock.json?

Comment: Такого нет в проекте.

Comment: В файле `npm-shrinkwrap.json` стоит "bootstrap": {
      "version": "3.3.7", хотя в папке установлена 4 версия... загадка... если нажму востановить пакеты то превратиться в 3.3.7

Comment: На самом деле я склоняюсь что это глюк VS, и просто в очередной версии они его исправят. Отключил у себя автообновление, и работает, обновляю что нужно вручную.